# How to allow a function to perform normally within expression()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression

I'm trying to partially italicize some labels but still have `sum()` function and I don't know how to do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

iris_mean <- aggregate(iris[,1:4], by=list(Species=iris$Species), FUN=mean) 
iris_sd <- aggregate(iris[,1:4], by=list(Species=iris$Species), FUN=sd) 
df_mean <- melt(iris_mean, id.vars=c("Species"), variable.name = "Samples", value.name="Values")
df_sd <- melt(iris_sd, id.vars=c("Species"), variable.name = "Samples", value.name="Values")
limits <- aes(ymax = df_mean[,"Values"] + df_sd[,"Values"], ymin=df_mean[,"Values"] - df_sd[,"Values"])
df_mean$Species <- factor(df_mean$Species, levels=unique(df_mean$Species), ordered=TRUE)

ggplot(df_mean, aes(Samples, Values, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + coord_flip() + 
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(angle=0, hjust=1)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,.5,0),"cm"),
    legend.key.size = unit(.5, "lines"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face = "italic")
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete("", 
                   labels= expression(
                     paste(italic("I. setosa"), " (n=", sum(iris == "setosa"), ")"),
                     paste(italic("I. versicolor"), " (n=", sum(iris == "versicolor"), ")"),
                     paste(italic("I. virginica"), " (n=", sum(iris == "virginica"), ")")))
```

Current plot:

[image: Current plot]

Desired plot:

[image: Desired plot]

Comment: You have an effective answer but you should realize that inside an expression-call the `paste` function has different syntax that it does outside that setting. In particular, there is no 'sep'-argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just looking at the scale_x_discrete, you can do

```
scale_x_discrete("", 
     labels= c(
        bquote(italic("I. setosa")*" (n="*.(sum(iris == "setosa")) * ")"),
        bquote(italic("I. versicolor")*" (n="*.(sum(iris == "versicolor")) * ")"),
        bquote(italic("I. virginica")*" (n="*.(sum(iris == "virginica")) * ")")))
```

Here we use `bquote()` to "insert" values into expressions. We do this with the `.()` function inside the `bquote()` call which evaluates the expression in the current environment and inserts the value into the expression.

You could automate the creation of these with

```
x <- c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")
xlabels <- lapply(x, function(spec) {
    bquote(italic(.(paste("I.", spec)))*" (n="*.(sum(iris == spec)) * ")")
})
```

and then use

```
+ scale_x_discrete("", labels= xlabels)
```